# Telecommunication(s)

Tags: grammatical-number

Are *telecommunication* and *telecommunications* interchangeable, or are there some contexts where one is preferred?  For example, the Wiki page on “Telecommunication” has a section entitled “Telecommunication networks,” but the main article on this topic is called “Telecommunications network.”  Is it that the singular is used when the main concern is the act of transmitting information in the abstract, but the plural when the writer wants to stress the various media involved?

There might be a similar issue with *communication(s)* as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is solely with *communication(s)*, the *telephone* per se does not alter much (it could be any form of communication that present the same issues).

I think [oxforddictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/communication) gives a nice overview:

> 1 [MASS NOUN] The imparting or exchanging of information by speaking, writing, or using some other medium:
>   *television is an effective means of communication*
>   *at the moment I am in communication with London*
>   
>   1.1 [COUNT NOUN] A letter or message containing information or news:
>   *a telephone communication*
>   
>   1.2 The successful conveying or sharing of ideas and feelings:
>   *there was a lack of communication between Pamela and her parents*
>   
>   1.3 Social contact:
>   *she gave him some hope of her return, or at least of their future communication*
>
> ---
>
> 2 (communications) Means of sending or receiving information, such as telephone lines or computers:
>   *satellite communications*
>   [AS MODIFIER]: *a communications network*
>   
>   2.1 [TREATED AS SINGULAR] The field of study concerned with the transmission of information.
>   *After studying communications and political science, he was soon ready for more wanderings.*
>
> ---
>
> 3 (communications) Means of travelling or of transporting goods, such as roads or railways:
>   *a city providing excellent road and rail communications*

According to this, it seems that the *headline* for the wikipedia section was written with the idea of using *communication* as a mass noun to modify network. In the actual text under the heading, they use *communications*, though, using it as in definition **2** as a plural modifier.

I would say this looks like an inconsistency, although both uses can probably be defended. It looks like they tried to be consistent with other headlines like *Communication channels* on the same page.

When used in the singular, *communication* is used in the same way other (mass)nouns can be used as a modifier: *water works*, *salt mines*. It does seem though, according to oxford dictionaries, that the “proper” form is the plural, *communications*.

On the other hand, in the case of *channel*, I think I have ever seen it used in that way! And neither has [google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%22communication+channel%22%2C%22communications+channel%22&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%22%20communication%20channel%20%22%3B%2Cc0).

The [learners dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/communication) gives as an example of use *communications system*, but again, I have more often seen and heard *communication system*. And once again, so did [google ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%22communication+system%22%2C%22communications+system%22&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%22%20communication%20system%20%22%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%22%20communications%20system%20%22%3B%2Cc0).

In conclusion, it seems the votes are not yet in on how to use *communication* exactly. Considering we have advanced several decades (or even more than a century depending on how you count) into what many proclaim to be the *communciation(s) era*, that *is* a bit disappointing. I'd say that whichever form you use, especially when using the word as a modifier, at least you should try to be consistent. I would have written the wiki-headline with an *s*.

---

<sub>**note:** *I don't know what is wrong with my ngram links, but it seems one has to click on the “search lots of books” button to display the graph...*</sub>

Comment: ODO adds that 'telecommunication' as a count noun is in a formal register.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - I think that is correct. In a less formal register, one would not have a communication, but a talk or even a chat. But as a modifier, it seems the dictionary favours the (countable or plurale tantum) _communications_ more than usage suggests. Could it be that actual _usage_ is more formal than dictionaries tell us? I would normally expect that the other way around...

Comment: :-) Are there two oerkelens/es? It's unusual for a plural (or plural-form) noun to be chosen as a modifier, and, I think, very unusual for there to be a choice. As to actual usage, I'm personally not exposed to any of the usages on a regular basis, so can't really comment. Perhaps 'communications' is modelled on 'media', an attempt (perhaps subconscious) to distinguish one-off occurrences from the whole infrastructure.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth — there are more of us than you'd expect :) I was confused myself, since I _do_ encounter both _communications network_ and _communication channel_ regularly in my line of work. You may be on to something with _media_, and let me add _data_, when it comes to grammatically-confused (new) technical jargon...

Comment: I'll certainly let you add _data_. I've got at least one dictionary that licenses the **word**.

Comment: I think that you are lacking a negative in _I think I have ever seen it used in that way!_... Either **never** or **don't**?

Answer (score 0):

[Telecommunications:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Telecommunications)

> - 1. Sometimes, telecommunication. (used with a sing. v.) the science and technology of transmitting information, as words, sounds, or images, over great distances, in the form of electromagnetic signals, as by telegraph, telephone, radio, or television.
>   2. Usu., telecommunication. the act or fact of communicating in such a manner.

Source:http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Telecommunications

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Telecommunication%2CTelecommunications%2C%20telecommunication%2C%20telecommunications&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CTelecommunication%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CTelecommunications%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctelecommunication%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctelecommunications%3B%2Cc0) shows a much  wider use of 'telecommunications' vs ' telecommunication'.